# How can I capitalize the necessary letters to return properly capitalized sentences? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is what I have. Any suggestions would greatly help. Thanks!:

```
function fixGrammar(input) {
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if(i === 0){
      input = input[i].toUpperCase() + input.slice(1);
    }  if(input[i] === (/\s[i+ ]/g)) {
        let capitalize = input[i].toUpperCase()
    } if(input[i] === '.') {
        let afterPeriod = input[i+2];
        afterPeriod.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  return input;
  }

console.log(fixGrammar("there's something you learn in your first boot-camp. if they put you down somewhere with nothing to do, go to sleep — you don't know when you'll get any more." ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on periods with any number of trailing spaces, uppercase the first character of each sentence, then join the array on a period and a space.

```js
const paragraph = `there's something you learn in your first boot-camp. if they put you down somewhere with nothing to do, go to sleep — you don't know when you'll get any more.`;

const capitalizeSentences = (str) => {
    return str
        .split(/\.[\s]+/)
        .map((sentence) => `${sentence[0].toUpperCase()}${sentence.slice(1)}`)
        .join('. ');
};

console.log(capitalizeSentences(paragraph));
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare a letter with a regex using `==` and hope to find a match. Also that regex `/\s[i+ ]/g` would look for white space followed by a literal `i` or literal `+` or a space.

You can use a regex to spot the letters that need to be capitalized, and replace them with `replace`:

```js
const fixGrammar = s => s.replace(/(?<=^|\. )\w/g, c => c.toUpperCase());

console.log(fixGrammar("there's something you learn in your first boot-camp. if they put you down somewhere with nothing to do, go to sleep — you don't know when you'll get any more." ));
```

Comment: Ah nice solution, my regex is rusty :D

Comment: Nice use of a callback in `.replace()`, I forgot we can do that

Comment: what does the c => c. represent? Is the c just a variable for the first letter of the word?

Answer (score 1):

One liner solutions FTW:

Sol 1:

```
input.split(". ").map(
  m => 
    m[0].toUpperCase() + m.slice(1) // `m[0]` gets the first character, `m.slice(1)` skips the first character and collects the rest of them together.
 ).join(". ")
```

Sol 2: Or you may make it more verbose:

```
input.split(". ").map(
    ([firstChar, ...restChars]) => 
       firstChar.toUpperCase() + restChars.join("") // `restChars` would be an array of characters, so we are joining them to get the original substring
    ).join(". ")
```

In the first sol, m.slice(1) will return string, but if you were to do the same for array, lets say ["a", "b", "c"].slice(1); it would return a *new* array ["b", "c"].

---

PS: `input` is the variable which has the string value. You may use it inside your `fixGrammar` function. Solution mentioned here assumes that there would be exactly one space after the dot!